# wordpress session and cookie handling from outside

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have 2 problems with cookies and sessions while using WP.

1)
I have custom CMS where I set a cookie. Cookie's path is / so it should work on every path on current domain.

Problem is wordpress can't read it (its not in developer console either).

My guess is they unset cookies which are not theirs?

2)Similar thing goes with sessions

if I set session from my CMS it's not readable (again empty).
I tried setting

```
session_start();
```

in the wp-config.php but does not work. If I set session variable inside wp-config.php then it works, but that's not what I want.

Can anyone suggest me fix or workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code into your functions.php file for sessions:

```
function register_my_session()
{
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start()
  }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Now if you want to use sessions its:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'tjcafferkey';
```